# how to navigate from a collection view after selecting didselectitem to another collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I have been trying to make a project which should content `collectionView` which nagivates to another `collectionView` after selecting an item from it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
var imgURLArray = [String]()

var nameArray = [String]()
final let urlString = "https://unembittered-vector.000webhostapp.com/JSON/alljson.txt"
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.downloadJsonWithURL()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Materials")!)

            if let actorArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "Materials") as? NSArray {
                for actor in actorArray{
                    if let actorDict = actor as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = actorDict.value(forKey: "name") {
                            self.nameArray.append(name as! String)
                        }/*
                        if let name = actorDict.value(forKey: "dob") {
                            self.dobArray.append(name as! String)
                        } */
                        if let name = actorDict.value(forKey: "image") {
                            self.imgURLArray.append(name as! String)
                        }

                    }
                }
            }


            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}


func downloadJsonWithTask() {

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    var downloadTask = URLRequest(url: (url as? URL)!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20)

    downloadTask.httpMethod = "GET"

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadTask, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)

        print(jsonData!)

    }).resume()
}


//Number of views
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return imgURLArray.count

}

  //Populate view
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
    print("test")
    cell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    let imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLArray[indexPath.row])

    if imgURL != nil {
        print("check")
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as? URL)!)
        //cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)
        cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)

    }
    else{
        print("error")}
    //cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row] + ".JPG")
    return cell
}

/*func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
    //vc.imageString = imgURLArray[indexPath.row]
    //vc.nameString = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    //vc.dobString = dobArray[indexPath.row]

    //cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: array[indexPath.row] + ".JPG")
    //return cell1

    //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)    
}*/
}
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: i m new at ios .. i want to go to another collection view after clicking on item at collection view i made in above code .

Comment: Please tell us what you want exactly.

Comment: i wud be appreciated if you guys could help me out with any example regarding navigating from a collection view to another view that is not detail view but another collection view .. @PGDev

Comment: You can navigate from one UIViewController to another UIViewController. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how you can implement what you are looking for:

**1. Storyboard**

[image]

**2. View Controllers**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Reply if you face any issue.

Comment: Did you achieve what you required?

Comment: Can you help me out with an example for collection view which load data from json with image and clicking an item from the view to navigate to another page with collection view which again load data from json . @PGDev

Comment: Yes, but I couldnt be able to navigate to another collection view yet