# Need to execute existing storyboard from collectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

There is a controller `ProductCardController` and a collection view. It is necessary to display another storyboard when clicking on a cell. Tell me how can this be done? `present` is not working.

```
class ItemsCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    ...
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //code here
    }

    
}
```

present and protocol - not work

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726560/choose-cell-in-collection-view-to-new-controller, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69139761/opening-another-viewcontroller-when-clicking-on-cell-of-collectionview, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860840/how-to-navigate-from-a-collection-view-after-selecting-didselectitem-to-another

Comment: @SwiftNewbie Value of type 'ItemsCollectionView' has no member 'navigationController'

Comment: where is your "ProductCardController" ? I mean in "Main" storyBoard or in another storyBoard ?

Comment: @SwiftNewbie in Main

Comment: @SwiftNewbie from controllers it works, but from collectionview this error

Comment: these may helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532869/how-can-i-navigate-to-a-viewcontroller-from-a-collectionviews-didselectitemat-w, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52329278/how-to-navigate-from-an-embedded-collection-view-s-cell-to-another-view-controll, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435005/pushing-to-new-viewcontroller-from-collectionview-cell-didselectitemat-programma, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996499/how-to-navigate-to-new-view-controller-from-collection-view-cell-in-swift

Comment: @SwiftNewbie it didn't help me(

Comment: Can you show more code about pushing/presenting `ProductCardController`? Is it a xib file or inside a storyboard?